# Removing extra white space when using first-letter

Tags: html, css

When I make the first letter of a paragraph bigger then the rest of the text it adds extra whitespace under the first line. Is there a trick/hack to removing this whitespace? I tried padding and margins on p::first-line to no avail

```
p{ line-height: 1.4; }
p::first-letter { font-size: 450%; }
```

See codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgGRjE

Comment: Another suggestion in addition to the answers below I would give is to float the letter left.  This is so you can create a drop cap effect.  You can see an explanation in [this CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/drop-caps/) and here is a [demo using your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogyNWz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 450%;
    line-height: 0em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reset `vertical-align` or/and `line-height`:

```css
p{
  line-height: 1.4;
}
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 450%;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  line-height:0.5em;
  
}
```

```html
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 450%;
  line-height:60%;
}
```