# Remove the space under the line after using ::first-letter

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am just trying to layout some type of information page that has the question and then there is a it's answer. I have applied some indentation and make the first letter bigger of the paragraph. The problem is that there is a extra space under the first line. I don't want the extra space that is appeared after using `::before-letter` pseudo selector. have any idea or trick...
Here is the code :

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: rgb(236, 195, 141);
        }

        ul {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            list-style: none;
        }

        li {
            margin: 15px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        section {
            background-color: rgb(194, 175, 212);
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }

        h1 {
            margin: 10px 0;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        p {
            text-align: justify;
            padding-right: 50px;
        }

        p::first-letter {
            font-size: 55px;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: rgb(236, 195, 141);
            height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="main">
        <h1>What you know about Technology?</h1>
        <p class="para">Technology is the important part of our day to day life. We get up in the morning from the
            ringing of our alarm clocks and go to bed at night after switching our lights off. All these luxuries
            that we are able to afford are a resultant of science and technology. Most importantly, how we can do
            all this in a short time are because of the advancement of science and technology only. It is hard to
            imagine our life now without science and technology. Indeed our existence itself depends on it now.
            Every day new technologies are coming up which are making human life easier and more comfortable. Thus,
            we live in an era of science and technology.

            Essentially, Science and Technology have introduced us to the establishment of modern civilization. This
            development contributes greatly to almost every aspect of our daily life. Hence, people get the chance
            to enjoy these results, which make our lives more relaxed and pleasurable. If we think about it, there
            are numerous benefits of science and technology. They range from the little things to the big ones. For
            instance, the morning paper which we read that delivers us reliable information is a result of
            scientific progress. In addition, the electrical devices without which life is hard to imagine like a
            refrigerator, AC, microwave and more are a result of technological advancement.
        </p>
    </section>
    <footer>All rights reserved 2021</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731510/removing-extra-white-space-when-using-first-letter

Comment: hey thanks but i searched it why i can't found this??

Comment: Should have searched like `Remove extra space ::first-letter`

Comment: okay i wil take care about it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is neat enough, but you can fix it by adjusting its `line-height`.

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: rgb(236, 195, 141);
        }

        ul {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            list-style: none;
        }

        li {
            margin: 15px 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        section {
            background-color: rgb(194, 175, 212);
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }

        h1 {
            margin: 10px 0;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        p {
            text-align: justify;
            padding-right: 50px;
        }

        p::first-letter {
            font-size: 55px;
            padding-left: 30px;
            line-height: 0.8;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: rgb(236, 195, 141);
            height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="main">
        <h1>What you know about Technology?</h1>
        <p class="para">Technology is the important part of our day to day life. We get up in the morning from the
            ringing of our alarm clocks and go to bed at night after switching our lights off. All these luxuries
            that we are able to afford are a resultant of science and technology. Most importantly, how we can do
            all this in a short time are because of the advancement of science and technology only. It is hard to
            imagine our life now without science and technology. Indeed our existence itself depends on it now.
            Every day new technologies are coming up which are making human life easier and more comfortable. Thus,
            we live in an era of science and technology.

            Essentially, Science and Technology have introduced us to the establishment of modern civilization. This
            development contributes greatly to almost every aspect of our daily life. Hence, people get the chance
            to enjoy these results, which make our lives more relaxed and pleasurable. If we think about it, there
            are numerous benefits of science and technology. They range from the little things to the big ones. For
            instance, the morning paper which we read that delivers us reliable information is a result of
            scientific progress. In addition, the electrical devices without which life is hard to imagine like a
            refrigerator, AC, microwave and more are a result of technological advancement.
        </p>
    </section>
    <footer>All rights reserved 2021</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but this one changes my position of the paragraph i mean when i use this my paragraph become above to its original location..